# C# WinForms trayapp MenuItem mouse hover detection

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem, mousehover

I have a fairly simple question, but I'm failing to find the solution. I have an application that resides in the task tray. When a user right clicks the tray icon, the program displays a menu of MenuItems. I would like to execute code when some of my MenuItems are mouse hovered over.

Is this possible?

Can you send me in the right direction?

I am using NotifyIcon

```
        trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
        trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);

        trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        trayIcon.Text = "blah";

        trayIcon.Icon = new Icon("favicon.ico", 40, 40);
        trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
        trayIcon.Visible = true;
```

Comment: **What buttons?** You just described a menu containing menu items. I don't see buttons anywhere.

Comment: @cody My apologies. I'm not typically a .Net developer and didn't think about that word choice conflicting with the .Net control "Button." I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: bdeetz, are you using NotifyIcon control in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `MouseHover` or `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of each menuitem.

**Update**:
Yep, NotifyIcon controls have a property named ContextMenuStrip. You'll have to create the ContextMenuStrip control to display the menu. It contains items of ToolStripMenuItems type. I tried to create a simple prototype - `MouseHover` works just fine.

Comment: MenuItems don't expose those events

Comment: I don't think these events exist -- at least [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.aspx)

Comment: yeah, but you're using ContextMenuStrips with ContextMenuItems with the notifyIcon control, unfortunately this controls don't provide any Select events ;)

Comment: Justin - check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. After moving my code to use ToolStripMenuItem instead of MenuItem, I was able to grab the EventHandler for MouseHover. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want the MenuItem's [Select event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.select.aspx):

> This event is typically raised when
>   the user places the mouse pointer over
>   the menu item. The event can also be
>   raised when the user highlights a menu
>   item using the keyboard by scrolling
>   to the menu item with the arrow keys.

Comment: Downvoter - answer is correct as question specifies MenuItems are used. If you disagree, it's helpful to leave a comment explaining why (unless, of course, you are an AC)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/254525/Automatically-display-Menu-on-Hover

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.menuStrip1.Items[0].MouseHover += new EventHandler(Form1_MouseHover);
}


void Form1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ToolStripDropDownItem)
    {
        ToolStripDropDownItem item = sender as ToolStripDropDownItem;
        if (item.HasDropDownItems && !item.DropDown.Visible)
        {
            item.ShowDropDown();
        }
    }
}
```